# Deprecated function set_cookie() in MX Mobile Detect add-on

Tags: mobile, mx-mobile-detect

I'm using [MX Mobile Detect](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/mx-mobile-device-detect) by Max Lazar but it doesn't seem to have been updated for a while. Specifically, the Developer Log is showing the following error;

Deprecated function set_cookie() called in /third_party/mobile_detect/pi.mobile_detect.php on line 238.

Deprecated since 2.8. Use EE_Input::set_cookie() instead.

I'm just wondering how I should modify this line?

```
$this->EE->functions->set_cookie( 'mx_mobile_device', $this->cache['mx_mobile_device'], $this->cookie_expire );
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use it like this:

```
$this->input->set_cookie('mx_mobile_device', $this->cache['mx_mobile_device'], $this->cookie_expire );
```